# Navigator.share() not copying text on mobile Firefox, specifically (it seems) on Pixel phones

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, share

I have an online game at https://gtkmysteries.com/murdle/ with a social share feature. It uses Navigator.share() to share the winning message on mobile devices. It seems to work on all of them, yet I sometimes have people complain, specifically, about it not working on a Google Pixel phone using Firefox as the mobile OS. I do not know why, but on those devices, it only copies the title and the link, and does not share the text.

```
function shareNow() {

var text_to_share = newSocialShareFormat();

window.mobileAndTabletCheck = function() {
  let check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};

console.log(text_to_share);

if ((navigator.share) && (window.mobileAndTabletCheck())) {

    navigator.share({
        title: 'MURDLE by G. T. Karber',
        text: text_to_share,
        url: "https://gtkmysteries.com/murdle"
      });

} else {
    
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text_to_share + "https://gtkmysteries.com/murdle");
    
    var share_buttons = document.getElementById("share-buttons");
    
    share_buttons.innerHTML = '<p style="text-align: center"><input TYPE="button" NAME="button" style="background: #A30B37" value="COPIED TO CLIPBOARD"></p><p style="text-align: center"><input TYPE="button" NAME="button" value="SHARE ON FACEBOOK" onClick="shareOnFB()"></p><p style="text-align: center"><input TYPE="button" NAME="button" value="SHARE ON TWITTER" onClick="shareOnTwitter()"></p>';
    
}

}
```

Can anybody identify why this might be so? I don't have a Pixel (and am, sadly, a mystery writer instead of a programmer), so my ability to debug across devices is very limited by not only my resources but also my knowledge.

Thank you very much for any suggestions or tips!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, but according to the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#browser_compatibility) and [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_share_data_text_parameter), Firefox on Android devices does not yet support `data.text` parameter passed to `Navigator.share(data)`.

Comment: Seems like a limitation.